# prime divisor of $3n+2$ proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, prime-factorization

I have to prove that any number of the form $3n+2$ has a prime factor of the form $3m+2$. Ive started the proof

I tried saying by the division algorithm the prime factor is either the form 3m,3m+1,3m+2.

Case 1: $3m$
     suppose $3m$ does divide $3n+2$. That means $3mr=3n+2$ where $r$ is some integer. But we get $mr-n= 2/3$ and since $mr-n$ is an integer that's a contradiction. Thus $3m$ does not work.

Case 2: $3m+1$
Same argument here

Case 3: $3m+2$
By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic every integer is divisible by a prime. But not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Your case 2 is very well possible.

Comment: I've corrected the title and the problem statement: please check to make sure I've conveyed what you intended, given your proof.

Comment: Alternatively, say all the primes $p_i$ such that $p_i \mid N$ were $p_i \equiv \{0,1\}\ (3)$, then $N \equiv \{0, 1\} \not\equiv 2\ (3)$.

Comment: $14=3\cdot 4 +2$ does have a prime factor $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$, namely, $7$. So, as @azimut says, you can't conclude that $n$ does not have such a prime factor.  You can only prove that such prime factors are not the only prime factors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,N = 3n+2\,$ has no prime factors of form $\,3k+2,\,$ then all prime factors must have form $\,3k+1,\,$ hence their product $\,N\,$ has form $\,3k+1,\,$ contra $\,N = 3n+2.$

**Generally** any factorization of an integer $\not\equiv 1\!\pmod{\!m}\,$ must include a factor $\not\equiv 1\!\pmod{\!m}\,$ simply because integers $ \equiv 1\!\pmod{\!m}\,$ are closed under multiplication (form a *monoid*).  Similarly for other sets of integers closed under multiplication. Consider the set T of integers divisible by $10,\,$ i.e. those with unit digit $= 0.\,$ Any factorization of an integer $\,n\not\in T\,$ must include a factor $\not\in T,\,$ else all factors have unit digit $= 0\,$ thus so too does their product $\,n,\,$ i.e. $\,n\in T,\,$ contra hypothesis. Similarly, one could let $\,T\,$ be all powers of $\,10,\,$ etc. This property of factors of elements in the *complement* of $T$ is just an equivalent *complementary* restatement of the closure of $T$ under multiplication.

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/45158/242) on the *complementary* view of subgroups, which generalizes: integer $\times$ noninteger = noninteger; $\ $  rational $\times$ irrational = irrational, etc.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**:

Denote the prime factorization of $3n + 2$ by $$3n + 2 = p_1^{e_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{e_r}$$ and consider this equation modulo $3$.

EDIT: Since other people have posted a full solution in the meanwhile, I'll do the same:

Modulo $3$ you get $$2 \equiv p_1^{e_1} \cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{e_r}\pmod{3}.$$ Now assume that all prime factors $p_i$ are equivalent $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$. Then also $p_1^{e_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{e_r}$ is equivalent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$. Contradiction.

Comment: No case 2 doesn't work I think. If it did then the statement I'm proving be wrong.

Comment: No and no. Look at the example of @ThomasAndrews: 14 = 2\cdot 7. The prime factor $7$ is of the form $3m + 1$. The claimed statement is still true, since the other prime factor $2$ is of the form $3m + 2$.

Comment: I figured out case three I think.

Answer (score 4):

If $(3n+2)$ is prime, then it has a prime factor $(3n+2)$.

If $(3n+2)$ is composite, then there exist integers $h,k$ where $1< h,k <(3n+2)$.

Case 1: if at least one of $h,k$ be of the form $3m+2$ then there is nothing to prove.

Case 2: if at least one of $h,k$ be of the form $3m$ then, $3|(3n+2)$
i.e. $3|2$ a contradiction. So
any integer of the form $(3n+2)$ has no prime factor of the form $3m$.

Case 3:if at least one of $h,k$ be of the form $3m+1$ (say $h$).
then $3$ cases arises for $k$

- subcase 1: $k= 3p$ which is impossible by case $2$.
- subcase 2: $k=3j+1$, then $3n+2 = 3(3mj+m+j)+1$ which is again a contradiction.
- subcase 3: so we must have $k$ of the form $3m+2$.

combining all the cases we have the required result.

Comment: Nice! Using basic properties..

Answer (score 3):

We will assume that by number we mean *positive integer*.

Call a number of the form $3n+2$ which has *no* prime divisor of the form $3m+2$ **bad**. We will show that there are no bad numbers.

Suppose to the contrary that there is at least one bad number. Then there is a **smallest** bad number $b$.

It is clear that $b\ne 1$. It is also clear that $b$ is not prime. For if $b$ is prime, then it has a prime divisor of the form $3m+2$, namely itself.  So there are integers $k$ and $l$, both bigger than $1$, such that $b=kl$.

If one of $k$ or $l$ is divisible by $3$, then so is their product. But $b$ cannot be divisible by $3$. For if $3$ divides $3n+2$, then $3$ must divide $2$, which is not the case.

If both $k$ and $l$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, then so is their product. But $b$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$.

Thus at least one of $k$ and $l$ (in fact exactly one) is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. Let it be $k$.

Because $k\lt b$, by the definition of $b$ as the smallest bad number, $k$ cannot be bad. It follows that $k$ is divisible by a prime $p$ of the form $3m+2$. But then so is $b$, contradicting the fact that $b$ is bad.

**Remark:** A proof that uses the fact that every integer $\gt 1$ is a product of primes is more efficient. Note that we do not need the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, aka the Unique Factorization Theorem. It is enough to have **a** factorization.

Comment: How is b not prime?  For n=1, 3n+2 = 5 which is prime.  Similarly, there are other values of n for which 3n+2 is prime so your argument is lacking proof there as n=3,5, and 7 would also have the characteristic of being prime.

Comment: If $b$ is prime, then it has a prime divisor of the form $3m+2$, namely itself, so it is not bad.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a proof by induction. The case $n=1$ yields $3n+2 = 5$, which is a prime so all is well. Now assume $n > 1$. If $3n+2$ is prime, we are again done. If not you can write it as $3n+2 = rs$ with $r,s < 3n + 2$. It is easy to show that either $r$ or $s$ also has to be of the form $3m + 2$. Applying the induction hypothesis gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

OK, starting from the case 2:

$$3n+2=r(3m+1)$$
$$3(n-mr)=r-2$$
$$k=n-mr=\frac{r-2}{3}$$
$$r = 3k+2$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Actually looking at it now no its not correct. I need to redo my entire proof.

Comment: This formula shows that if a number of the form 3n+2 is divisible by a number of the form 3m+1, $\frac{3n+2}{3m+1}=3k+2$$ for some integer k. If this 3k+2 is not a prime factor, you can repeat this for a finite number of times and produce a prime factor that is in the form 3k+2.  I'm pretty sure this is accurate. Your statement that case 2 shows that it can't be divisible by 3m+1 is incorrect but I think this one is.

Comment: these type of questions that ask things like if these numbers take this form then prove that it its also this form seemingly is confusing me. Does anyone know of a website or another book that explains this concept well?