# Proof - There're infinitely many primes of the form 3k + 2 — origin of $3q_1..q_n + 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, intuition, proof-verification

[Origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195057/85100) — Elementary Number Theory — Jones — p28 — Exercise 2.6

To instigate a contradiction, postulate $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n$ as all the primes $\neq 2 (=$ the only even prime) of the form $3k+2$. Consider  $N=3q_1q_2\dots q_n+2.$ None of the $q_i$ divides $N$, and $3 \not | N$.

$N$ = 3(the product of odd numbers) + 2 = odd number + even number = odd. Because $N \ge 2 $,
$\color{brown}{♯}$ because $N$ is odd $\implies 2 \not | N$,
thence by $\color{brown}{♯}$ and the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, N =  a product of one or more $\color{brown}{odd}$ primes.
[The prime divisors of $N$ cannot be *all* of the shape $3k+1$. *At least one* of these primes is of the form $3k+2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320643/prime-divisor-of-3n2-proof) — Why? $(3a + 1)(3b + 1) = 3(...) + 1$, thence any number of (not necessarily distinct) primes of the form $3k+1$  is itself of the form $3k+1$.

But $N$ is not of the form $3k+1$. So **some** prime $p$ of the form $3k+2$ divides $N$. Overhead in first paragraph, we proved $q_i \not|N$ for all $i$. Therefore $p \notin$  $\{q_1,\dots,q_n\}$ of primes of the form $3k+2$, contradiction.

1. [The general proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195420/85100) just starts with primes. Therefore how can you prefigure this proof's different start with odd primes ?
2. Where did this choice of $N$ hail from — feels uncanny?
3. I don't understand how none of the $q_i$ divides $N$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if the following observations help:

1. Different statement $\Rightarrow$ different proof :-)
2. $N$ was chosen to be of form $3k+2$ *precisely* to guarantee that it must be divisible by at least one prime of the form $3k+2$.
3. Look at the form of $N$: It was chosen so that $(N-2)$ is divisible by all of $q_i$, so if $N$ was to be divisible by $q_i$ too, $q_i$ would have to divide $2$. But that's impossible, since $q_i$ is an odd prime and thus strictly greater than $2$.
4. If you multiply several natural numbers and at least one of them is even, the product will be even. Thus, if we're looking at an *odd* number and its factorization to primes, no even prime (i.e. no $2$) can occur in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Purport that you start with all primes of the form $3k+2$ including $\color{red}2$, thence you start with $M = 3q_1 ... q_n \color{red}2 + 2$ You will quickly realize that the argument don't work, because $\color{red}2$ always divides $M$ and we want a number outside the list to divide $M$. You would not be able to conclude that there are primes of the form $3k+2$ NOT on the list.
   So remove $\color{red}2$ from the list is just a natural thing to do.
2. You want a number that doesn't divide any primes on the list and is of the form $3k+2$. You know that the number have to be of the form $3k+2$. So start out by thinking what is the possible value of $k$. If $k$ is not divisible by a prime $q_{i}$ on the list, you will quickly find that $q_{i}$ divides $N$. Because you want all $q_{i}|k$, their product $\Pi \, q_i$ is just one possible choice.
3. $q_{i}$ divide $N-2$ by definition. So if $q_{i}$ divide $N$ too, you end up with $q_{i}$ divide $2$, which is not possible because $q_{i}$ is odd and is a prime.
4. $N$ is odd so it is not divisible by any even number, prime or not.

Comment: Thanks. Upvote. Can you please explain and work out 'If $k$ is not divisible by a prime $q_i$ on the list, you will quickly find that it would be difficult to rule out the possibility that $q_i$ divide N. So make you want k to be divisible by all $q_i$, and their product is just one possible choice.' I'm flustered by this.

Comment: @DwayneE.Pouiller: let's say your list of $q_{i}$ consist of 3 primes $5,11,17$ and you want to find a prime number not on the list. Now let's say you pick $k=561$, with this value $5$ does not divide $k$ but $11$ divide $k$ and $17$ divide $k$. With this value of $k$ you have $3k+2=1685$. Easily check that now both $11$ and $17$ does not divide $3k+2$. However, we got a problem: $5$ divide $3k+2$ so this simple argument are not enough to show that there are primes of that form outside the list $5,11,17$. If you picked $k=935=5\times 11\times 17$ instead you would not have that problem.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you please move your comment into your answer and answer only in your answer? How'd you pick $k = 561$? Is it by reason of $561 = 3.11.17$? I refashioned your answer to 2 - edify me if it's astray.